# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error within for loop

Tags: javascript, iframe, business-catalyst

I am trying to write code in which multiple searches and iframes work together to achieve specified results. I am building this site in business catalyst, so it uses WebApps.

Currently I am trying to submit a search into an iframe and then return a dynamic value to the parent window via form fields. I have been receiving the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error in response to my code. If anyone could help me by taking a look at my code I would be very appreciative. Thank you!

NOTE: The {module_webappresults} tag is part of business catalyst. When this is rendered on the page a series of divs with values is output to the DOM, several of these items will change the value of the variables.

```
var chapNum = null;
var chapter1ID = 0;
var chapter2ID = 0;
var chapter3ID = 0;
var chapter4ID = 0;
var chapter5ID = 0;
var chapter1 = false;
var chapter2 = false;
var chapter3 = false;
var chapter4 = false;
var chapter5 = false;
</script>
    <div id="results">{module_webappsresults,,_self,true,-1,,1}</div>
    <form name="chapter-ids" id="chapter-ids" action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="chap-id-1" id="chap-id-1" class="cat_textbox" value=""/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="chap-id-2" id="chap-id-2" class="cat_textbox" value=""/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="chap-id-3" id="chap-id-3" class="cat_textbox" value=""/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="chap-id-4" id="chap-id-4" class="cat_textbox" value=""/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="chap-id-5" id="chap-id-5" class="cat_textbox" value=""/>
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="total-chapters" id="total-chapters" class="cat_textbox" value=""/>

    </form>
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i <= chapNum; i++) {
                var formID = chap-id-[i];
                document.getElementById(formID).value = chapter[i]ID;
                parent.chapterData(this.form.formID.value)
        };
        document.getElementById('total-chapters').value = chapNum;
                parent.totalChapters(this.form.total-chapters.value)
        document.write(chapNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better store your chapters as elements in an array :

```
var chapters = []
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) chapters[i]= {ID:i, value:false};
```

Right now, if you really want to keep them as variables, you can access them with

```
window['chapter'+i+'ID']
```

instead of

```
chapter[i]ID
```